# Error 500: Requested Resource Too Large to Return, responseTooLarge

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I'm working on an application that polls Admin API(G Suite) and traverse the logs. While working on it, one of our client is facing following errors :

- "Unable to retrieve list of activities"
- "Error 500: Requested Resource Too Large to Return, responseTooLarge"

The above condition is also taken care of in Drive API V2(https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/quickstart/go) under Step 3. However there's no documentation regarding the same and I'm unable to replicate the scenario. Therefore, I would like to know about the replication steps of this issue.